# I'm making a GUI Program, but getting a weird error

Tags: java, compiler-construction, constructor

I made this program for my homework, I have to add one GUI choice to another.

The sum of the two choices are not appearing in the  Total charges per semester button.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**

        The Main class creates the GUI for the Dorm and 
        Meal charges.
 */

public class Main extends JFrame
{
private JPanel dormPanel;
private JComboBox dormBox;
private JPanel mealPanel;
private JComboBox mealBox;
private JPanel totalChargesPanel;
private JPanel selectedMealPanel;
private JPanel buttonPanel;
private JButton calcButton;
private JLabel label1;
private JTextField totalCharges;

private String[] dorm = { "Allen Hall: $1,500 per semester", 
        "Pike Hall: $1,600 per semester", 
        "Farthing Hall: $1,200 per semester", 
"University Suites: $1,800 pe  r semester"};

private String[] meal = { "7 meals per week: $650 per semester", 
        "14 meals per week: $1,095 per semester", 
"Unlimited meals: $1,500 per semester"};

/**
    Constructor
 */
public Main()
{
    super("Dormitory and Meal Plan");

    // Specify an action for the close button.
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Create a BorderLayout manager.
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    // Create the dorm and meal panel.      
    buildDormPanel();
    buildMealPanel();
    buildSelectedTotalChargesPanel();
    buildButtonPanel();

    // Add the components to the content pane.   
    add(dormPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(mealPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(totalChargesPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    // Pack the contents of the window and display it.    
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

// The buildDormPanel method builds the dorm panel. 
private void buildDormPanel()
{
    // Create the dorm panel.      
    dormPanel = new JPanel();
    dormBox = new JComboBox(dorm);

    // Register the action listener.      
    dormBox.addActionListener(new ComboBoxListener());

    // Add the dorm panel to the panel.
    dormPanel.add(dormBox);
}

// The buildMealPanel method builds the meal panel. 
private void buildMealPanel()
{
    // Create the meal panel.      
    mealPanel = new JPanel();
    mealBox = new JComboBox(meal);

    // Register the action listener.
    mealBox.addActionListener(new ComboBoxListener());

    // Add the meal panel to the panel.
    mealPanel.add(mealBox);
}

// The buttonPanel method builds the bottun panel.
private void buildButtonPanel()
{
    // Create a panel.
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();

    // Create a button.
    calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");

    // Register an action listener with the button.
    calcButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    // Add the button to the panel.
    buttonPanel.add(calcButton);
}

// The buildSelectedDormPanel builds the selected totalCharges panel.
private void buildSelectedTotalChargesPanel()
{
    // Create the totalChargesPanel for the label.      
    totalChargesPanel = new JPanel();
    label1 = new JLabel("Total charges per semester: ");

    // Create the totalCharges textfield.        
    totalCharges = new JTextField (25);
    totalCharges.setEditable(false);

    // Add the totalChargesPanel to the panel.      
    totalChargesPanel.add(label1);
    totalChargesPanel.add(totalCharges);
}

/** Private inner class that handles the event when the user 
     selects the dorm and meal boxes.
 */
private class ComboBoxListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        // Variables to hold the dorm, meal, and total charges.        
        String dorm = (String) dormBox.getSelectedItem();
        String meal = (String) mealBox.getSelectedItem();

        // Calculates the total.
        totalCharges.setText(meal + dorm);
    }
}

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        // Add code below
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Main();
}
}
```

Comment: are you selecting anything from the combo box?

Comment: Please, for the love of `$DEITY`, [format your code so it's readable](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), especially if you're going to just dump your entire program into the question.

Comment: What does `one GUI choose to another` mean?

Comment: You're leaving us all hanging -- you say you're getting a "weird error" but never tell us what it is.  Seriously, you should post any error messages, even if Howard is smart enough to figure out what it is without one.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels:  I don't think he understands what an error is.  "The sum of the two choices are not appearing in the Total charges per semester button." implies that it's not working as expected.

Comment: @Greg: You may be right, but the key word for me is "weird" suggesting he's seeing something more than just no correct output.  But heck we may as well be discussing next month's weather as no one can tell what he was thinking til he comes back and clarifies things.

Answer (score 2):

In your action listener I find the following code:

```
// Variables to hold the dorm, meal, and total charges.        
String dorm = (String) dormBox.getSelectedItem();
String meal = (String) mealBox.getSelectedItem();

// Calculates the total.
totalCharges.setText(meal + dorm);
```

You read strings from each combobox and then try to calculate the total. Unfortunately the term `meal+dorm` does not mean addition if applied to strings but string concatenation.

To solve this issue you may select a proper data structure which saves display text+value for each entry in the comboboxes, then calculate total of the values in your actionlistener and afterwards put this total to text format again.